# How do I unit test a method that uses TransactionTemplate.execute and verify the code executed inside execute()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How do I unit test the below code?

```
public Mono<MyObject> create(MyObject myobject)
{
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
        try {
            return myRepository.save(myobject);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new ...;
        }

    })).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

In my current test I can do the following below, but I also want to mock the `myRepository.save()` and verify execution with `Mockito.verify()`.

```
@Mock
private transient TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

@Test
void test() {
    when(transactionTemplate.execute(any())).thenReturn(myObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some comments on your questions:

1. For testing of Mono/Flux behavior it is recommended to use [StepVerifier](https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher#stepverifier)
2. If you mock *transactionTemplate*, then mocking of *myRepository.save()* is meaningless
3. The mocking of *myRepository.save()* could be meaningful in another test, where you will test the proper work of actual *transactionTemplate.execute()*

Comment: I am using StepVerifier, but I also want to `verify()` that `myRepository.save()` or other things were executed inside `transactionTemplate.execute()`

Comment: So, this would be the separate test of actual transactionTemplate with mocked myRepository, as I already proposed. Such test would not belong to unit tests of your code above, it belongs to transactionTemplate